# Understanding percentiles of child or constituent distirbutions

Tags: distributions, quantiles, histogram

Consider an example where a user performs some operation on a web page and total time taken for that operation is some of 2 parts. I.e.,

Total time = Part1 time + Part2 time.

What we currently have is histogram for each of these components i.e., Total, Part1  time and Part2 time. When we calculate weighted percentiles from these histograms, i.e. P90, they dont add up. i.e.,

P90 Total time != P90 Part1 time + P90 Part2 time

This is expected as these are 3 different distributions by themselves.

Question is whats the recommendation in handling this kind of data, when the purpose would be determine if Part1 or Part2 is the culprit for performance issues?

Currently, example data looks like this:

Total - 1000
Part1 - 700
Part2 - 600

Comment: What happens when you regress performance on all three variables?

Comment: Valid question. Increase in either Part1 or Part2 or both of them will increase the Total as well. But what we are trying to understand is exactly the same, i.e., whether only Part1 or Part2 has increased or both. Not just the trends, we are interested in the current snapshot as well. I.e., what is my Total, Part1, and Part2 for last 24 hours. With individual P90s, it becomes inconclusive.

Comment: What do you mean by `determine if Part1 or Part2 is the culprit for performance issues`?

Comment: Still unsure what you're asking or what you're trying to do here. Sounds like you want to get something like a table with columns' being part_1, part_2 (and total which is the sum), and rows being individuals, but you only have aggregate distribution for each part... and you're wondering if there's a way to back the table out of the aggregated data?

Comment: You can approach this with copulas, eg: if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the cumulative distribution functions for the two histograms, you can consider variables $u$ and $v$ which are both standard normal, with correlation $\rho$, and then model the total time as $F_1^{-1}(\Phi(u)) + F_2^{-1}(\Phi(v))$.